# Time series classification with surrounding steps

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, signal-processing

I have the time series dataset bellow:

[image]

This is the graph of the first 21000 steps :

[image]

I want to detect the 'P' Label (red axis on the graph) for new data. The record with 'P' Label depend on the 25 steps before and 25 steps after.

Is this a binary classification problem ?
If so what would be the best approch to resolve this exercice (CNN, RNN, ..) and how should I process the data for input ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to find a suitable solution?